# Wordpress custom post type not appearing in wp-admin left nav-bar

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am new to WordPress and hence learning to make custom plugins. For this purpose, I have taken a fresh Bluehost account to practice things on it. As this account is fresh, no other plugin is installed over it.

Following [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668) tutorial, I make a custom plugin. That plugin appeared in the plugins tab. But when I activate it, the Custom post type does not appear in WP-admin left nav-bar. I then followed another tutorial, but the same thing happened. My DEBUG is on, but no error gets thrown. I have tried all solutions given on google but no result.

Plugin file:

```
function tutsplus_register_post_type() {
 
    // movies
 
    $labels = array(  
        'name' => __( 'Movies' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'add_new' => __( 'New Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'new_item' => __( 'New Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'view_item' => __( 'View Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Movies' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No Movies Found' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Movies found in Trash' , 'tutsplus' ), 
    );
 
    $args = array(
 
        'labels' => $labels, 
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'public' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false, 
        'supports' => array( 
            'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' 
        ), 
        'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'movies' ), 
        'show_in_rest' => true 
    ); 
}

add_action( 'init', 'tutsplus_register_post_type' );
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to `register_post_type`. try the below code.

```
function tutsplus_register_post_type() {
 
    // movies 
    $labels = array(  
        'name' => __( 'Movies' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'add_new' => __( 'New Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'new_item' => __( 'New Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'view_item' => __( 'View Movie' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Movies' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No Movies Found' , 'tutsplus' ), 
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Movies found in Trash' , 'tutsplus' ), 
    );
 
    $args = array(
 
        'labels' => $labels, 
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'public' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false, 
        'supports' => array( 
            'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' 
        ), 
        'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'movies' ), 
        'show_in_rest' => true 
    ); 

    register_post_type( 'movies', $args );
    
}
add_action( 'init', 'tutsplus_register_post_type' );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]